# how to get the datatable name from xsd file

Tags: c#, datatable, xsd

Here I am having two xsd files like one.xsd and two.xsd etc.

In one.xsd there are 3 datatables and in two.xsd there are 2 datatables. From that one.xsd file I need to get all the 3 datatable names into combobox.

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "*.xsd"))
{
         string[] strxsd = file.Split('\\');
         string str = strxsd[7].ToString();
         DataTable tblFiles = new DataTable();
         tblFiles.Columns.Add("Filename");
         DataRow dr = tblFiles.NewRow();
         dr[0] = str;
         tblFiles.Rows.Add(dr);
         dtfill.Merge(tblFiles);
         cmbXsd.DataSource = dtfill;
         cmbXsd.DisplayMember = dtfill.Columns[0].ToString();
         cmbXsd.ValueMember = dtfill.Columns[0].ToString();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're going to get hammered out here for not showing code, examples of what you've tried, etc.  Please edit your post and add some detail or try searching this site for similar questions.

Comment: By using this code I filled the xsd filenames into combobox,now that xsd files is having datatables,I need to fill that datatable names into another combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         if (cmbXsd.SelectedIndex == 0)

            {
                cmbDt.Items.Clear();
                XmlDataDocument xmldd = new XmlDataDocument();
                DataSet ds = xmldd.DataSet;
                for (int j = 0; j <= dtfill.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    string filename = dtfill.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                    string dirpath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename);
                    ds.ReadXmlSchema(dirpath);
                    DataTableCollection dtc = ds.Tables;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtc.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[i];
                        GetTableNames(ds);
                        break;
                     }
                    break;
                }
            }
```